# remove div only on one page in Django template

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have a website that contains 15 seperate pages. On each page I have a div named header. Right know I am removing this element via JavaScript like this:

homepage.html

```
<script>
    const element = document.getElementById('header');
    element.remove();
</script>
```

The problem is that I can see the header element for a second before it is removed. The script is placed on the top of the page. I also tried to do it via css like this:

```
.header {
    height: 0rem !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

However, I still see the element disappearing when refreshing the page.

I know that I could create a template block in my `base.html` file and just exclude it in the homepage.html page but I'd need to include it in the other 14 HTML files manually.

**Question**
Is there any other/better way to exclude div so I don't see it at all on my homepage?

Answer (score 1):

Django's templating system gives you a vast flexibility to manipulate any content on any view once you understand how its **{% block %}** tag works, especially in relation to extended (child) templates.

In your case, what you can do is to wrap your header html in **base.html** like so:

```
{% block my_header %}
<div class="header"></div>
{% endblock header %}
```

Now, in the **homepage.html** you simply add this (assuming it extends base.html):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
...
{% block my_header %}{% endblock header %}
```

With this piece of code you're telling Django to overwrite header block with nothing. I also recommend reading upon **{{ block.super }}**.

Answer (score 0):

with css

```
.header {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I still can see the header when refreshing. It is disappearing after 1 second